# What does MongoClient.getDB return when the argument database does not exist on the host?

Tags: mongodb

I was reading through the source code for MongoClient.getDB but I can't make sense of it. What happens if you call mongoClient.getDB(name) where there is no such database as name?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

It creates the db for you. The grepcode source code makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a philosophy of creating things implicitly as they are used.

When you call Mongo.getDB with an unknown database name, you get a database object representing a database which doesn't exist yet but which behaves as if it does.

The database is created on the hard drive the moment you insert the first document into it.

Comment: No that's not right, it actually creates a database when you do it.

Comment: @philipp is correct, calling getDB() doesn't create the database on the server, only inserting a document into the database creates it. You can "ls" the list of files in the dbpath on the server to confirm this for yourself. getDB() does not, in fact, communicate with the server at all.